# Beginner: Creating a list with divisors

Tags: python, list

I just started learning Python and am stuck with an exercise.
The program should ask the user for a number and then print out a list including all of the number's divisors.

```
myList = []
usernumber = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
a = int(1)

for a in range(1, usernumber):
    while usernumber % a == 0:
    divisor = usernumber / a
    myList.append(divisor)
    a += 1

print(*myList)
```

This seems to work for everything except 1, but I can't figure out what I have to change to make it work for an input of 1. Any ideas?

Comment: What output do you want for 1?

Comment: Yeah @khelwood There are a lot of logical errors and syntactical errors. I just skimmed through the question quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
myList = []
usernumber = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
#No need to declare a as an integer, for loop does that for you.

for a in range(1, usernumber+1):

    #usernumber+1 as range() does not include upper bound.

    #For each number leading up to the inputted number, if the
    #remainder of division is 0, then add to myList.

    if usernumber % a == 0:
        myList.append(a)

print(myList)
```